# Google analytics Behavior Flow everything ends at home page

Tags: analytics, behavior

can someone help me with google analytics? I such a problem with Behavior Flow. Everything immediately ends after someone entry to a page.

Does anyone know why is this happening? I will be grateful for every help.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your website might be redirecting them so for GA, they are considered dropped off because they are not tracking the final destination.

The redirect destination and the final destination are not under the same domain.

Maybe.